# i18next and jest testing translations changes

Tags: jestjs, i18next

Hi I try to test my modified i18next
with jest framework, I try to test default language and then changing the language and receive correct translation

my code looks like that

```
const i18next = createI18nextContext();
//loading i18n files etc

i18next.on('loaded', () => {

    expect(i18next.t('test')).toBe('start-translations');

    changinglanguagefunction();
    expect(i18next.t('test')).toBe('changed-translations');
    done();
})
```

In that case I spotted that i18 create 2 threat so I try to use,

```
18next.on('initialized', () => {
```

then I get timeout. How Can I get only one threat?

Comment: Have you already looked into: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Answer (score 0):

A solution was to add promise

```
   function i18OnLoad(i18next: i18n.i18n) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    const loaded = () => {
    i18next.off("loaded", loaded);
    resolve();
    };
    i18next.on("loaded", loaded);
    });
    }
```

And add

```
await i18NextOnLoad(i18next);
```

in test